# Data Frame, wrong summary

Tags: r, dataframe, summary

I have a pretty big dataframe, called FTSE. Here his structure.

```
str(FTSE)

'data.frame':   21167 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Name         : Factor w/ 2 levels "FTSE MIB","FTSE MIB NET TOT ": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ DateLastTrade: Factor w/ 18 levels "12/10/13","12/11/13",..: 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 ...
 $ LastPrice    : num  19091 19008 19002 19018 19018 ...
 $ Open         : num  19091 19091 19091 19091 19091 ...
 $ LastClose    : num  19021 19021 19021 19021 19021 ...
```

I tried to summarize it, I've obtained:

```
summary(FTSE)
                Name        DateLastTrade     LastPrice          Open         LastClose    
 FTSE MIB         :10289   12/3/13 : 1370   Min.   :17750   Min.   :17811   Min.   :17805  
 FTSE MIB NET TOT :10878   12/4/13 : 1370   1st Qu.:18124   1st Qu.:18055   1st Qu.:18124  
                           12/6/13 : 1370   Median :18321   Median :18310   Median :18313  
                           12/2/13 : 1369   Mean   :18366   Mean   :18375   Mean   :18352  
                           12/5/13 : 1369   3rd Qu.:18595   3rd Qu.:18752   3rd Qu.:18697  
                           12/23/13: 1353   Max.   :19091   Max.   :19091   Max.   :19021  
                           (Other) :12966
```

Pay attention at the "LastPrice" column.
If I try to summarize directly LastPrice (variable that I actually need in my analysis) I've obtained this, that is pretty different from previous.

```
summary(FTSE$LastPrice)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  17750   18120   18320   18370   18600   19090
```

I'm pretty a newbie on R and I really can't figure why values are different. It's a rounding issue? I've read a lot of answers about this but I can't find a solution to uniform the results.
I'm really stuck on this problem.

Thanks to anybody that could help me or even try to understand my problem.
Regards

EDIT for shujaa:

```
max(FTSE$LastPrice) 
[1] 19091.3

FTSE[which.max(FTSE$LastPrice), ]
      Name DateLastTrade LastPrice    Open LastClose
1 FTSE MIB       12/2/13   19091.3 19091.3  19021.48
```

Comment: Are there missing values (`NA`) in the `LastPrice` column at all?

Comment: @RichardScriven I could see that making the quantiles different, maybe, but the Max is different!

Comment: Please post a few lines of the data, with `dput(head(data))`.  Are you using `quantmod` here?

Comment: A couple things I'm curious about: 1. can you replicate this with subsets of the data? What if you use just 10000 rows, 15000 rows, etc. 2. If `LastPrice` is always integer (as it appears to be), try converting it with `as.integer()` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I'm also curious which one's right. What do you get for `max(FTSE$LastPrice)` and `FTSE[which.max(FTSE$LastPrice), ]`?

Comment: @shujaa, numbers are not integers but double, like you see from the last command in EDIT part in question. Madness :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a rounding problem. All the output from `summary(FTSE$LastPrice)` has only 4 significant digits. If you look at `?summary` in its `Usage` section you see the default for digits (as a named argument) coupled with the default for digits as an option gets your to 4.

```
 # summary(object, ..., digits = max(3, getOption("digits")-3))

> getOption("digits")
[1] 7
```

So try:

```
summary(FTSE$LastPrice, digits=7)
```

An unanswered question remains, however: Why does the summary.data.frame function not do the same degree of rounding, since the default argument to digits is the same for the `.default` and the `.data.frame` methods? Looking at the code you see that summary.data.frame actually first does `summary.default` on its columns with a fixed value of digits=12L, and later uses the digits argument to `format`. It seemed to me that the help page was somewhat obscure in this area in it arguments description

```
digits: integer, used for number formatting with signif() (for summary.default) or 
                                                 format() (for  summary.data.frame).
```

It completely ignores the fact that the default (and fixed) signif for data.frame columns is quite different.

Answer (score 1):

The `method` for summary on `data.frame` is different then the default method for a `vector`. Probably resulting in using a different precision for computation. [Read more here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/Methods.html). If you explicitly specify digits, it works:

Lets create the data:

```
nr <- 21167
set.seed(nr)
temp <- data.frame(Name=sample(c("FTSE","FTSE NET"),nr,replace=T),
                   DateLastTrade=sample(1:18,nr,replace=T),
                   LastPrice = sample(18000:21000,nr,replace=T),
                   Open = 19091,
                   LastClose = 19021
                   )


str(temp)
```

Now lets reproduce what you got:

```
summary(temp)
summary(temp$LastPrice)
```

Now lets fix that:

```
summary(temp,digits=7)
summary(temp$LastPrice,digits=7)
```

Note: This will only work if your numbers are <10^7-1, i.e. if they have <= 7 digits. You'll not see the effect at 10^7, but if 10^7+1 is there, then the last digit will be rounded down to zero. To solve that you'll have to increase digits to 8 (and so on). It is safer to use a larger value, e.g. `digit=10`